# Only rendering a frame at a time?

Tags: rendering

I'm rendering pngs for an animation, and all was going fine, but 3/4 of the way through it stopped, and now it needs me to click "animation" to render each png, rather than just going to the next frame on it's own. My frame step and end frame are correct, and all was going well until frame 120/150

Comment: That's one of the situations where a blend file would be really helpful

Comment: When you render an image sequence you need to render as animation. Either by pressing the animation button on the render section or by pressing Ctrl+F12.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Blender interface]

all you have to do is change where it says start: 1 at the bottom where it says start to whatever frame you got to. So in your case it stopped at 120 so change start to 120 and end to 150 (or whatever frame is the last one in your render.)

Comment: Instead of changing the frame range, just uncheck the **Overwrite** box inthe output settings. That way blender will render only the frames that have not been rendered, leaving the existing ones untouched.